# How does the complexity of work done in a thread impact the overall code performance

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Threads are used to reduce the execution time, wherever possible. Would using threads for complex works impact the performance of the overall code anyhow?

Comment: Wondering: do you still have questions regarding the answer you got? If not, and your problem is solved, please consider accepting at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading **always** comes with a certain overhead: additional CPU cycles are spent on managing the state of threads, context switching, etc, pp.

Meaning: whether "using more threads" improves "performance" **always** depends on context. Example: threads become extremely helpful regarding latency/responsiveness when long-running IO operations are handled in separate threads. So thread A might wait for such an IO operation to complete, while thread B can continue to do something else. If there would only be one thread, the whole program would sit there, doing nothing but waiting.

But if your code is mainly doing "heavy computations", then adding threads might only **cost** you for no gain.

And of course, remember that python has a [global lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) on thread anyway.